# Receiving error during automake command in ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu, automake

I want to install a tool named [mfcuk](https://github.com/nfc-tools/mfcuk), but the following errors appear. What shall I do?

```
itsme@ubuntu:~/Desktop/mfcuk-master$ ls
AUTHORS         ChangeLog  configure.ac  INSTALL  Makefile.am  README  TODO
autom4te.cache  configure  COPYING       LICENSE  NEWS         src     tools
ebrahim@ubuntu:~/Desktop/mfcuk-master$ sudo automake
configure.ac: error: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found.
configure.ac: You should verify that configure.ac invokes AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE,
configure.ac: that aclocal.m4 is present in the top-level directory,

configure.ac: and that aclocal.m4 was recently regenerated (using aclocal)
configure.ac:7: error: required file 'config.h.in' not found
src/Makefile.am: error: required file './depcomp' not found
src/Makefile.am:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'depcomp'
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am: error: am__fastdepCC does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   The usual way to define 'am__fastdepCC' is to add 'AC_PROG_CC'
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am: error: AMDEP does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   The usual way to define 'AMDEP' is to add one of the compiler tests
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:     AC_PROG_CC, AC_PROG_CXX, AC_PROG_OBJC, AC_PROG_OBJCXX,
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:     AM_PROG_AS, AM_PROG_GCJ, AM_PROG_UPC
/usr/share/automake-1.14/am/depend2.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again
itsme@ubuntu:~/Desktop/mfcuk-master$
```

Update1: output of `cd src; make`:

```
itsme@ubuntu:~/Desktop/mfoc-master$ cd src;
itsme@ubuntu:~/Desktop/mfoc-master/src$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
itsme@ubuntu:~/Desktop/mfoc-master/src$ cd src; make
bash: cd: src: No such file or directory
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
itsme@ubuntu:~/Desktop/mfoc-master/src$
```

Comment: print output of  cd src; make

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run autoreconf first,  It compiles all the relevant tools in the correct  order and installs the missing files.

```
autoreconf -vfi
```